# Property 'punteggioMassimo' not found on type com.xxx.yyy.model.Questionario

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

After I debugged the code and watched how the object `Questionario` is made I can see that there is no property `punteggioMassimo`, even if it is declared on the class.

```
//QuestionarioBase.java

public class QuestionarioBase extends com.xxx.cms.classgenerator.BaseBean implements Serializable {

//some other properties

protected Integer punteggioMassimo;

//some other getter and setter

public Integer getPunteggioMassimo() {
    return punteggioMassimo;
}

public void setPunteggioMassimo(Integer punteggioMassimo) {
    this.punteggioMassimo = punteggioMassimo;
}
```

This class is extended by `Questionario.java` which has nothing in it.

```
public class Questionario extends QuestionarioBase implements Serializable {

}
```

When the object is created in the controller it initializes all the properties besides `punteggioMassimo`. I also tried to force the initialization using the `setPunteggioMassimo` in the Expression tab of eclipse, but I had no luck with it!

Here is a picture of the Expression tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the object is created in the controller it initializes all the properties besides punteggioMassimo.

This means to me that your Ide is not taking into account your changes. If you are in Eclipse, clean projects, clean install maven, maven update project, clean tomcat or whatever application server, and then redeploy from scratch. Now you are sure you have the latest version of your class... If using something else, just try to find out if your class is actually deployed, by opening (unzipping) your war (or jar) and checking if your changes are in there. If not, it means there is something wrong with the build process...

Comment: thanks for the answer, but not luck with that :/ same error.

Comment: do you use maven modules?

Comment: no, just looked at my pom and there are no modules defined there :(

Comment: could you add information on how you deploy and how you debug? maven/ant/hot-deploy/... remote debugging/eclipse built-in debugging... your code is totally fine...

Comment: I debug with the eclipse built-in debugging tool. Btw i just received the new source code and now it works correctly! thanks for your patience and advices!